# NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification unable to understand if object is deleted

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using private child queue (parent queue = `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`)  to delete an object and in my controller I'm listening to `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`.

The goal is to understand if a given object (that is displayed in controller) was deleted. Object is fetched in main queue (with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`).

Here is the code:

```
    let savingContext = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext
    let deletedObjects = savingContext.deletedObjects
    if deletedObjects.contains(myModel!) {
        myModel = nil
    }
```

After deleting object I get the notification and my objects exists there. The only problem, that they have different objects

```
deletedObjects: [<model: 0x7fab705e5ca0> (entity: model; id: 0xd000000000b00002 <x-coredata://B60C4E0B-EE90-49DE-8E51-3A3C75763994/Model/p44> ; data: {
    // same values here
})], 

mymodel:(<model: 0x7fab705e2090> (entity: model; id: 0xd000000000b00002 <x-coredata://B60C4E0B-EE90-49DE-8E51-3A3C75763994/Model/p44> ; data: {
    // same values here
}))
```

So `myModel = nil` is never executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful about what you are doing here, as it looks like you may be building a Rube Goldberg machine... and one that may end with a nasty explosion.

Since you didn't give enough details in your question, I have to make some assumptions... and hope it doesn't bite me...

Anyway, it appears that you are watching the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` for the child context, and comparing the deleted object with an object obtained from the main/parent context.  This will not work (and can be dangerous to boot).  The two contexts contain completely separate objects.

You should compare the `NSManagedObjectID` objects instead of the managed objects themselves.

Better yet, if you want to know when the child has deleted an object in the parent MOC, you could monitor the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` in the main/parent MOC.  Note that this notification will occur anytime you change the MOC yourself, and not just when the child context saves.

However, the notification carries a nice set of information in its `userInfo` dictionary, including a set of deleted objects.